# Why does my code using insertMany() skips some of the records and insert same records multiple times?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I have 9577 unique records in a csv file.

This code inserts 9800 records and insert not all records, but duplicates of some of them. Any idea why it does not inserts the unique 9577 records and also duplicates of some of them? Below I also insert the remain part of the code so you get the whole picture

```
function bulkImportToMongo(arrayToImport, mongooseModel) {
  const Model = require(`../../../models/${mongooseModel}`);
  let batchCount = Math.ceil(arrayToImport.length / 100);
  console.log(arrayToImport.length);
  let ops = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < batchCount; i++) {
    // console.log(i);
    let batch = arrayToImport.slice(i, i + 100);
    console.log(batch.length);
    ops.push(Model.insertMany(batch));
  }
  return ops;

  return Promise.all(ops).then(results => {
    // results is an array of results for each batch
    console.log("results: ", results);
  });
}
```

I parse the csv file

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const path = require("path");
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

const promiseCSV = Promise.method((filePath, options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var records = [];
    csv
      .fromPath(filePath, options)
      .on("data", record => {
        records.push(record);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        // console.log(records);
        resolve(records);
      });
  });
});
```

And here is the script that connects it all together:

```
const path = require("path");
const promiseCSV = require("./helpers/ImportCSVFiles");
const {
  connectToMongo,
  bulkImportToMongo
} = require("./helpers/mongoOperations");

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../data/parts.csv");
const options = {
  delimiter: ";",
  noheader: true,
  headers: [
    "facility",
    "partNumber",
    "partName",
    "partDescription",
    "netWeight",
    "customsTariff"
  ]
};

connectToMongo("autoMDM");
promiseCSV(filePath, options).then(records => {
  bulkImportToMongo(records, "parts.js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//It looks like your issue is simply i++.  Perhaps you meant i += 100?

```
for (let i = 0; i < batchCount; i+=100 /* NOT i++ */) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: no it does not solve the issue... batchCount is how many batches the whole array has been divided in... I decrease the number os items in the csv file to 30 and decrease the batchlimit to 5. It generated 6 batchCount´s. I also did a console.log of arrayToImport and it was a length of 30 and all unique objects. But when I checked in the mongodb there where approx 9 different items that had been duplicated a couple of times, but the total number of documents was still 30...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I hope this helps other...  :-)

I had two errors, in the function promiseCSV (changed to parseCSV) and second I had bad logic in bulkImportToMongo.

Complete solution:

I parsed and imported 602.198 objects and here is how long time it took using node --max_old_space_size=8000 on a MacBook Pro with 8gb of ram.

**console**

```
➜  database git:(master) ✗ node --max_old_space_size=8000  partImport.js
Connected to db!
Time to parse file: : 5209.325ms
Disconnected from db!
Time to import parsed objects to db: : 153606.545ms
➜  database git:(master) ✗
```

**parseCSV.js**

```
const csv = require("fast-csv");

function promiseCSV(filePath, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.time("Time to parse file");
    var records = [];
    csv
      .fromPath(filePath, options)
      .on("data", record => {
        records.push(record);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.timeEnd("Time to parse file");
        resolve(records);
      });
  });
}

module.exports = promiseCSV;
```

**mongodb.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

function connectToMongo(databaseName) {
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${databaseName}`, {
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    useMongoClient: true
  });
  console.log("Connected to db!");
}

function disconnectFromMongo() {
  mongoose.disconnect();
  console.log("Disconnected from db!");
}

function bulkImportToMongo(arrayToImport, mongooseModel) {
  const Model = require(`../../../models/${mongooseModel}`);
  const batchSize = 100;
  let batchCount = Math.ceil(arrayToImport.length / batchSize);
  let recordsLeft = arrayToImport.length;
  let ops = [];
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < batchCount; i++) {
    let batch = arrayToImport.slice(counter, counter + batchSize);
    counter += batchSize;
    ops.push(Model.insertMany(batch));
  }
  return Promise.all(ops);
}

module.exports.bulkImportToMongo = bulkImportToMongo;
module.exports.connectToMongo = connectToMongo;
module.exports.disconnectFromMongo = disconnectFromMongo;
```

**partImport.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const parseCSV = require("./helpers/parseCSV");
const {
  connectToMongo,
  disconnectFromMongo,
  bulkImportToMongo
} = require("./helpers/mongodb");

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../data/parts.csv");
const options = {
  delimiter: ";",
  noheader: true,
  headers: [
    "facility",
    "partNumber",
    "partName",
    "partDescription",
    "netWeight",
    "customsTariff"
  ]
};

connectToMongo("autoMDM");
parseCSV(filePath, options)
  .then(records => {
    console.time("Time to import parsed objects to db");
    return bulkImportToMongo(records, "parts.js");
  })
  /*   .then(result =>
    console.log("Total batches inserted: ", result, result.length)
  ) */
  .then(() => {
    disconnectFromMongo();
    console.timeEnd("Time to import parsed objects to db");
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```